# Pipe delimiter in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, google-bigquery, command-line-arguments

I am trying to export a table from *BigQuery* to *Google CLoud Storage* (GCS) using `bq` command in a bat file. The command has a parameter to export as a Pipe delimited file. The command works from the CLI as it is but when I run from a bat file using the `call` command it opens the command but does not execute it. Note: Same operation runs without the pipe delimiter parameter.

Any idea why?

```
call bq extract -F^^^| my-project:my-dataset.mytable gs://myfolder/myfile.csv
```

This is the only line I have in my bat file. when I run from command line it works:

```
C:\bq extract -F^^^| my-project:my-dataset.mytable gs://myfolder/myfile.csv
```

Output:

> Waiting on bqjob_r01419067_00000169eed1d868_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE

When I run the bat file, `C:\test.bat`

Output:

> C:\bq extract -F^| my-project:my-dataset.mytable gs://myfolder/myfile.csv
>   C:\

Comment: Why are you using CALL? Why are you triple escaping the pipe delimiter? With some programs I use it is as simple as just quoting the delimiter you want to use. `-F "|"`. Using CALL will double all carets in the command.

Comment: I would also try `-F"^|"`

Comment: Hi @Squashman, I am using CALL because I have more commands to add and if I don't use it, processing stop after the first command. Quotes are not working

Comment: Did you try `-F"^|"`?  I found another [question on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911964/1417694) that said that does work.

Comment: Yes it works from the command line but not from bat file.C:\Users\myfolder>CALL bq extract -F"^|" my-project:mydataset.mytable gs://myfolder/Fact.csv                                     
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Now add one addtional caret `-F"^^|"`

Comment: Same result, sorry

Comment: I don't use BigQuery so I don't know what is inside the `bq.bat` file that would be treating the carets incorrectly.

Comment: See the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29620495/1417694) from @jeb

Comment: Wohoo! this works! thank you so much @squashman and @jeb!! set "caret=^"
CALL bq extract -F"%%CARET%%|" my-project:my-dataset.mytable gs://myfolder/myfile.csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF [Jeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29620495/1417694) solution is correct you should be able to change your batch file code to this.

```
set "caret=^"
call bq extract -F"%%CARET%%|" my-project:my-dataset.mytable gs://myfolder/myfile.csv
```